Gauge invariance of Hadamard point-splitting renormalization procedure
The current density of a charged complex scalar field in a background electromagnetic field $A_\mu$ is given by
$$ j^\mu = ie( (D^\mu \phi)^*\phi - \phi^*D^\mu \phi)$$
with $D_\mu = \partial_\mu + ieA_\mu$ the gauge covariant derivative.
This expression is of course gauge independent (under the U(1) gauge transformation $\phi \to e^{i\alpha}\phi$, $A_\mu \to A_\mu - \partial_\mu \alpha$).
What I don't understand comes when trying to understand why the renormalization scheme used in this article to calculate the vacuum expectation value of this quantity is gauge dependent, namely
$$ \langle j^0 \rangle = ie \sum_{n>0} \left( (\omega_n - A^0) \lvert \phi_n \rvert ^ 2
-(\omega_{-n} - A^0) \lvert \phi_{-n} \rvert ^ 2
\right) $$
while the one used in this other article isn't. Theirs looks something more complicated,
$$ \langle j^0 \rangle = ie \lim_{\tau\to 0}
 \sum_{n>0} \left( (\omega_n - A^0) \lvert \phi_n \rvert ^ 2 e^{i\omega_n(\tau + i\epsilon)}
-(\omega_{-n} - A^0) \lvert \phi_{-n} \rvert ^ 2e^{-i\omega_{-n}(\tau + i\epsilon)}
\right). $$ In the first article to calculate the charge current they just input the mode decomposition of the field in the vacuum expectation value, while in the second one they renormalize the vacuum expectation value of $j^\mu$ following Hadamard state point-splitting procedure.
I don't think however that the technicalities on how the renormalization is done is relevant. I have two main questions:

How does taking the vacuum expectation value of the charge density induce a gauge dependence?
How would one assert whether an expression like these is gauge invariant?


As I am posting this it seems kind of obvious that then the vacuum state must therefore not be gauge invariant. But how?
